# How to arrange $p-1$ non-zero elements into $A$ groups of $B$ where $p$ is a prime number

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields, cyclic-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number, and GF$(p)$ its finite field. If $G=[x,x^2,x^3,...x^c]$ is a cyclic group with multiplicative order $c$, then $x$ is a generator of group $G$. That is, the multiplicative order of $x$ in GF$(p)$ is $c$. The elements $e$ in group $G$ are precisely those such that $e^c=1$. If $e$ is any element which cannot be written as $x^k$ for any positive integer $k$, then there exists an element $m$ such that $mx^k=e$. Let $G_2=[mx,mx^2,mx^3,...mx^c], G_3=[m_2x,m_2x^2,m_2x^3,...m_2x^c], G_4=[m_3x,m_3x^2,m_3x^3,...m_3x^c],...G_d=[m_{d-1}x,m_{d-1}x^2,m_{d-1}x^3,...m_{d-1}x^c]$

where $m, m_2,... m_d$ are distict elements. There are $(p-1)/c=d$ distinct  groups such that each element $e$ is contained in exactly one group $G_n$. Let $D=[1,m,m_2,m_3,...m^{d-1}]$ be the group of distinct elements such that each of these elements will generate exactly one group (shown above).

It turns out that if $\gcd(c,d)=1$, then the elements contained in $D$ are those such that ${m_n}^d=1$.

What about when $\gcd(c,d)>1$ and:

- $c$ and $d$ do not have the same exact prime factors
- $c$ and $d$ have the same exact prime factors. That is, $c=a^b{a_2}^{b_2}{a_3}^{b_3}......{a_n}^{b_n}$ and $d$ = $c=a^c{a_2}^{c_2}{a_3}^{c_3}......{a_n}^{c_n}$.

Here is an example with the first case of $c$ and $d$ coprime:

$p=13, c=4, d=3$

Working in the field GF$(13)$ (the integers $\mod 13$) The first group $G$ is a cyclic group of order $4$: $[1, 5, 8, 12]$, and $1^4 = 5^4 = 8^4 = 12^4 = 1$. We have $d=3$, and $D=[1, 3, 9]$, it follows $1^3 = 3^3 = 9^3 = 1$. If every element in $D$ is multiplied with every element in $G$, we obtain the following groups:

$G: [1, 5, 8, 12]$, $G_2: [2, 3, 10, 12]$, and $G_3: [4, 6, 7, 10]$.

Every non-zero element in GF$(13)$ is included in exactly one of these groups.

If $c=2,d=6$, this approach doesn't work as $G$ is the cyclic group $[1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 12]$, $1^6 = 3^6 = 4^6 = 9^6 = 10^6 = 12^6 = 1$, and $D$ is the cyclic group $[1, 12]$, $1^2 = 12^2 = 1$. Multiplying every element in $D$ by every element in $G$ gives us two identical groups:

$G: [1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 12]$, and $G_2: [1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 12]$.

And not all non-zero elements in GF$(13)$ are included in one of these groups, unfortunately.

Does anybody have an approach around this?

Comment: I'm afraid I find your first paragraph very difficult to parse. What is $m$? What is $k$? Yes, given $x$, $e$ and $k$, the equation $mx^k=e$ defines a unique $m$, but it depends on the choice of $k$, and using a different $k$ leads to a different $m$. Mind you, the cosets $mG$ coming from different choices of $k$ are all the same (and all equal to $eG$). But, why do you call $G_2,G_3$ etc *groups*? Only $G$ is a group, the rest of them are *cosets* of $G$.

Comment: Reading further, I think you want $D$ to be a set of representatives of cosets of $G$. I also get a vibe that you would want $D$ to be a subgroup also. Or, failing that, consist of consecutive powers of an element. Here, as you observed, the first goal can be achieved if and only if $\gcd(c,d)=1$. This is because $GF(p)^*$ is cyclic of order $p-1$. Essentiall all you need to do is to invert the isomorphism $C_d\times C_c\simeq C_{p-1}$.

Comment: On the other hand, when $\gcd(c,d)=n>1$ we don't have that isomorphism. Another way of seeing the problem is that the equation $x^n=1$ has $n$ roots in $C_c$, $n$ roots in $C_d$, and consequently $n^2$ roots in $GF(p)$. But a polynomial of degree $n$ can have at most $n$ roots in a field.

Comment: What you can do in general is the following. Let $g$ be a generator of $GF(p)^*$, also known as a primitive root modulo $p$. Then, by the theory of cyclic groups, $G=\{1,g^d,g^{2d},\ldots,g^{(c-1)d}\}$. We immediately see that
$$GF(p)^*=G\cup gG\cup g^2G\cup\cdots\cup g^{d-1}G.$$ 
In other words, we can use $D=\{1,g,g^2,\ldots,g^{d-1}\}$ as the set of representatives. The price we pay is that $D$ is not a subgroup, the exponents of $g$ will overflow.

Comment: In your example case $p=13$ the element $g=2$ is a primitive root. In that case you see that $G=\{1,3,4,9,10,12\}$ and $2G=\{2,6,8,5,7,11\}$ form a partition of $GF(13)^*$.

Comment: I do think, I am not sure though, there are two separate cases to $\gcd(c,d)=n>1$. The first one is where $c$ and $d$ do not have exactly the same prime factors (example: $\gcd(30,20)=10$, and $30=2*3*5$, while $20=2^2*5$ (the prime 3 is not a factor). The second case is where $c$ and $d$ have exactly the same prime factors (example: $\gcd(48,54)=6$, and $48=2^4*3$, $54=2*3^3$ (Both have the same prime factors 2, 3, and these are the only prime factors of these numbers).

Comment: The example I worked on is an example of the first case where $c$ and $d$ don't have the same prime factors. An example for the second case would be $c=6$, $d=18$, $p=109$.

Comment: If $G$ is the group of elements of order $c$ and $H$ is the group of elements of order $d=(p-1)/c$, then all the elements of $GF(p)^*$ are of the form $gh$ with $g\in G, h\in H$ IF AND ONLY IF $\gcd(c,d)=1$. No extra cases are needed. The number of elements of $GF(p)^*$ that can be written in such form is $lcm(c,d)=(p-1)/n, n=\gcd(c,d)$. This is all basic theory of cyclic groups. I don't see how the number of prime factors of $n$ would be relevant.

Comment: It may be easier to work in the isomorphic additive group $\Bbb{Z}_{p-1}$. The subgroup $G$ consists of multiples of $c$. This has a non-trivial intersection with the other subgroup consisting of multiples of $d$ if and only if $\gcd(c,d)>1$. The multiplicative group $GF(p)$ is isomorphic to the additive group $\Bbb{Z}_{p-1}$, so the exact same phenomena occur (only multiplication becomes addition, and raising to a power becomes multiplication by an integer).